# Store large amount of string in a multi-dimensional array

Tags: java

I'm having a project that will suggest books to the user and i'm planning in making my application offline. My question is: Is it okay to store my large amount of Strings on my array? Multi-dimensional array to be exact. I'm planning in doing it this way.

```
public bookLibrary() { 
    public static String[][] books = {{bookID}, 
{bookTitle}, {bookGenre}, {bookPlot}, {etc}}
}
```

What do you guys think? Should I continue it this way? If using this Data Structure is slow, what else can I use to store data?

Comment: why not using some offline database for this? you'll get the power of SQL and it will consume much less resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must use Java... I recommend you encapsulate the book data inside a `Book` class. Your library can store the books in a `HashMap` to provide quick access and scale-ability. In fact, you could use several HashMaps together to allow you to reach the book according to any one of its features (e.g. author or genre).

The `Book` class might look like this:

```
class Book{

    HashMap<String, String> features;

    public Book(){
        this.features= new HashMap<String,String>();
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getFeatures() {
        return features;
    }

    public String addFeature(String key,String value){
        return features.put(key, value);
    }

    public void addFeatures(HashMap<String, String> newFeatures){
        this.features.putAll(newFeatures);
    }
}
```

Your `Library` class could use a HashMap of HashMaps:

```
HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Book>> library;
```

So, to access a book, you call

```
public Book getBook(String featureType,String key){
    return library.get(featureType).get(key);
}
```

The `featureType` string specifies whether you're looking up a book by author, genre, description, etc. The `key` is the specific author's name. For example, to get a book by Bob Smith, you would use `getBook("author","Bob Smith");`.

You can add books to the library as follows:

```
    public void addBookToLibrary(Book book){
        HashMap<String,String> bookFeatures = book.getFeatures();
        for(String featureType : bookFeatures.keySet()){
            HashMap<String,Book> libraryFeatureMap = library.get(featureType);
            libraryFeatureMap.put(bookFeatures.get(featureType), book);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at [relational database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database).

It is not good to store your data as you suggested - in an array. What would you suppose to happen if your app stops? All your data would be lost.

After that read about [ORMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). For Java one of the most popular is [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/orm/). Using is you will retrieve info into a data structure like the following one:

```java
List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();
```

And the *Book* is something like:

```java
public class Book {
    private Integer bookID;
    private String bookTitle;
    //etc, read about foreign key declration e.g.
    //then follow getters/setters
}
```

Also if you use [Eclipse IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/home/index.php), try to install [Hibernate Jboss tools](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/4.1.0.Final/en/hibernatetools/html_single/index.html). Using it you can generate a lot of useful code instead of writing it by yourself.

Comment: (Or NetBeansIDE and eclipseLink [JPA/ORM].) An embedded database like [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) would be painless to distribute.